# ¿Cómo hago para que el hover me cubra todo el texto?

Tags: css

Estoy desarrollando un menú o barra de navegación y le puse un hover de color más oscuro que el fondo para cada sección. El problema es que me gustaría que el hover cubra toda la sección y no solo la parte del texto. Más abajo dejo una imagen que muestra cómo queda actualmente y cómo quiero que me quede.

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  background: #8EF35E;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: green;
}

#index_menu {
  margin: 0px 83px 0px 70px;
}

#noticias_menu {
  margin: 0px 83px 0px 83px;
}

#objetivo_menu {
  margin: 0px 83px 0px 83px;
}

#ayudanos_menu {
  margin: 0px 83px 0px 83px;
}

#contacto_menu {
  margin: 0px 70px 0px 83px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="index_menu"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li id="noticias_menu"><a href="Noticias.html">Noticias</a></li>
    <li id="objetivo_menu"><a href="Objetivo.html">Objetivos</a></li>
    <li id="ayudanos_menu"><a href="Ayudanos.html">Ayudanos</a></li>
    <li id="contacto_menu"><a href="Contactanos.html">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

[image: Como me queda // Como quiero que me quede]

Comment: Seria buena idea que agregaras el `HTML`. para poder si quiera ver el problema que tienes. Saludos.

Comment: Es dificil ayudarte si no muestras el html!. Puedes verificar los elementos html y aplicarle css desde la herramienta del desarrollador. sería mucho más sencillo observar así los elementos internos y saber a cual especificamente quieres aplicarle el hover.

Comment: @edwinboada ahora agregue el html :)

Comment: @Daniel ahora agregue el html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios detallitos para empezar ve al siguiente enlace:
[menu en codepen](https://codepen.io/enriquemena444/pen/vYdNbBb)

Como puedes notar elimine todos los margenes además los padding de la clase menu. Logrando el efecto que deseas, ahora bien debes tomar en cuenta que si quieres que el mismo ancho y alto de un elemento interno html que el elemento contenedor debes establecerlo preferiblemente con el elemento contenedor en relative y el interno en absolute en su propiedad position, y jugar con los valores hasta que sea el correcto! . Aca debajo te pongo el código Css:

```
    .menu{
position: relative;
list-style: none;
background: #8EF35E;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0px;
align-items: center;

}
.menu li a{
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin:0 50px;
}

.menu li{
display: inline-block;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.menu li:hover{
background: green;

}
```

Comment: Podés insertar tu código como _snippet_, con el botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: @padaleiana mi dispositivo no soporta ese snippet. Por eso agregue el enlace, en dónde encontrarás la respuesta!

Comment: Excelente respuesta, tal cual lo que queria. Te agradezco un monton! Gracias por tomarte el tiempo :)

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de

```css
.menu li a:hover{
    background: green;

}
```

usa

```css
.menu li:hover{
    background:green;
}
```

Para que afecte toda la etiqueta li y no solo la etiqueta a que esta dentro de la etiqueta li

Comment: Lo intente y no me funcionó. Ahi deje el HTML asi se entiende mejor :)